# How do you achieve type casting in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have different message types defined under a wrapper.

For Example:

in test.proto

```
Message Wrapper {
    required Type type =1;
    optional MessageType1 msg1 =2;
    optional MessageType2 msg2 =3;
}
```

and SendData.cpp

```
sendData(int type, google::protobuf::MessageLite& proto) {
MessageWrapper wrapper;
wrapper.set_type(type);
switch (type) {
case type1:
     MessageType1* msg1 = wrapper.mutable_msg1();
     msg1.CopyFrom(proto);
     break;  
 }
case type2:
//

}
```

In this case `CopyFrom` throws me an error no matching function - candidates are `MessageType1::CopyFrom(const MessageType1&)`.

Any pointers on how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should do a regular C++ `static_cast`, i.e.:

```
msg1.CopyFrom(static_cast<MessageType1&>(proto));
```

Note that this of course requires that the input message is actually of this type, and it will crash if it isn't. You can use `dynamic_cast` instead to verify at runtime that the cast is safe, but that requires that RTTI is enabled, and it can be slow.

If you expect that the input message is actually not of the C++ type `MessageType1`, but is of a wire-format-compatible type, then you can try:

```
msg1.ParseFromString(proto.SerializeAsString());
```

I.e. serialize and then re-parse. This will be very slow, of course. Don't forget to check for an error return.

Answer (score 0):

Copyfrom expects to receive **MessageType1**.
Looks like you are trying to send to CopyFrom **MessageLite** instead of **MessageType1**

(by the way if you send the all the proto file we might see what is MessageLite, currently I can only guess its another message in your proto)

Comment: this is MessageLite - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite

Comment: When I want to pass a message to funcction Im using:https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message    and than cast it to the message I need. Maybe after you cast it CopyFrom will receive it?